# Check for required columns in MySqlBulkLoader c#

Tags: c#, mysql, bulkloader

Is there any way to validate the required columns when using MySqlBulkLoader ? I tried making the column in MySql table not nullable and no default. But still the values are getting loaded with no exception. Also, I wasnt able to find any documentation for the MySqlBulkLoader class.

Comment: `MySQLBulkLoader` can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html) and the MySQL Documentation can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net.html).  If this is what you need, I will change it to an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did see this and I have a similar code. I wasnt able to get the api information like MySqlBulkLoader.local, etc. I am trying to figure out if there is any way I can specify the number of columns expected. I directly load from a tab separated file into a table with predefined columns.